# EF Core | Unable to create a pivot table utilising the same model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a pivot table setup whereby I use the same model for both columns, to create almost a "whitelist" for columns that can reference one another.

```
export class Service {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set;
}
```

```
export class ServiceWhitelist {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int ServiceId { get; set; }

  public int TargetServiceId { get; set; }

  public Service Service { get; set; }

  public Service TargetService { get; set; }
}
```

I then try and setup the relationship in the parent service model...

```
public ICollection<ServiceWhitelist> ServiceWhitelist { get; set }
```

but upon doing so I can the following:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Service.ServiceWhitelist'

So I add in the following to the DbContext but still get errors thrown:

```
builder.Entity<Service>().HasMany(s => s.ServiceWhitelist).WithOne(sw => sw.Service);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I approaching this wrong as is there a better way to do this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two foreign keys from ServiceWhitelist you must associate the navigation property with the desired foreign key. And at most one of them can cascade deletes (at least in SQL Server).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
                .HasMany(s => s.ServiceWhitelists)
                .WithOne(s => s.Service)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceWhitelist>()
                .HasOne(sw => sw.TargetService)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(sw => sw.TargetServiceId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```